# array in array and foreach warning

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following array, generated from `$_SESSION`

```
array(1) { ["products"]=> &array(4) 
                { ["prod_count"]=> int(2) 
                           [0]=> array(1) { ["product_id"]=> int(4)}
                           [1]=> array(1) { ["product_id"]=> int(10) } 
                           [2]=> array(1) { ["product_id"]=> int(11) } } }
```

I try to use foreach to sort it.

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $key=>$my_value): ?>

   <?php foreach($my_value as $product_id): ?> 
     <?=$product_id?>   
   <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It works fine and I get the `product_id` but it also gives me warning:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /books_shop/templates/cart.php on line 6
```

which is this line:

```
 <?php foreach($my_value as $product_id): ?>
```

any idea what I'm missing here? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because not all value in your session is an array, make sure it's an array before to use it in a foreach loop using [*in_array*](https://www.php.net/in_array),

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $key=>$my_value): ?>    
   <?php if(is_array($my_value )) { 
            foreach($my_value as $product_id): ?> 
     <?=$product_id?>   
   <?php endforeach;  }  ?>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Preferred code structure,

```
if(is_array($my_value )) { 
    foreach($my_value as $product_id): 
       echo $product_id;
    endforeach;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check `$my_value` before passing it into foreach,

```
if (is_array($my_value)) {

  foreach ($my_value as $product_id) {
   //your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first element in `['products']` is `"prod_count"=> 2`, which is not an array.
try this:

```
  <?php foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $key=>$my_value){ ?>
       <?php if($key == 'prod_count') continue; ?>

       <?php if(is_array($my_value)): ?>
           <?php  foreach($my_value as $product_id): ?> 
               <?=$product_id?>   
           <?php endforeach; ?>
       <?php endif; ?> 
    <?php }; ?>
```